# Is Matt Murdock's Daredevil persona still public knowledge in the comics?

Tags: marvel, comics, daredevil, secret-identity

This is in the comic continuity, not the TV show, but at one point, Matt Murdock was outed as Daredevil. I know he turned down an invitation to the Avengers because of it, recommending Ronin to serve in his place. This was from *The New Avengers* a few years back (issue #11, 2005).

[image: The New Avengers issue front cover]

I failed to keep up with the story, so I don't know if this was retconned, if he took on a new identity, or much like the "history rewrite" of *One More Day* when Peter Parker's identity was reverted to being a secret, if something like that happened.

Can anyone provide any details, please?

Comment: Daredevil's secret identity has been revealed and re-hidden/forgotten several times.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Okay.... "rehidden" _how_ exactly? in what story did this happen, and who was responsible for it? I don't recall Mephisto making a deal with him, and considering it was broadcast, I'm surprised assassins didn't come to take him out.

Comment: The first time it happens, he ends up living a triple life and then fakes one of his own deaths who he stages as Dareveil. I'm not really too sure on each case though.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Links to the story?

Comment: Off the top of my head I can't remember but it happened way before _The New Avengers_ so isn't really an answer here anyway.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrotokay, I'll see if I can search around....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it isn't (currently). A new volume was started some years ago (volume 5, launched in 2016) where Daredevil's identity wasn't public knowledge anymore. The exact reason was voluntarily kept secret for a couple issues.

Reminder: the Purple Man is a powerful villain with psychic abilities. The Purple Children are some kids who share similar powers, and same purple skin.

Then, it was revealed in issue #20 of *Daredevil* (2015) that the Purple Children, that Daredevil had helped way earlier (*Daredevil* #10, 2014), wanted to pay him back. Purple Man used a machine to amplify his powers at some point; long story short the Purple Children turned it against him and used Purple Man's power to erase everyone's memory of Murdock being Daredevil.

Daredevil quickly realized nobody remembered anymore. Especially, he wouldn't believe Foggy did not recognize him (when under the mask), and unmasked himself before Foggy, who went into quite a shock.

So far not many "ordinary" folks have regained that knowledge.

Comment: Well, that seems definitive. A little Dues Ex Machina, but better than a deal with a devil . Thank you, chick. You rock.